# Best way to get the exact total search results in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

When I try to get the total search results using `search:estimate` I get the wrong results.. when I try to parse the total from `search:search`, it also gives me wrong or from one page to another page I get different total count.

How can I get the exact count for my search string ?

---XXXX EDITED the Question ------

My database consists of JSON documents and these JSON documents are hierarchical in structure. for eg: Following is sample, I kept at the end of the post.. Sorry for pasting my whole JSON structure, but I think you get the idea..

I created Field(s)/Field(s) Range index on certain elements like

```
concept_species /species
concept_name    /name
concept_registrar   /registrar/name
cept_scientist  /scientist/name
concept_supplier    /suppliers/name
concept_entitySubType   /entitySubType
concept_entityType  /entityType
concept_createdDate /createdDate
concept_project /project/name
concept_moniker /moniker
```

*When my search has one of these as "constraints" then my xdmp:estimate is fine.. but when I do not have any of these constraints on my search string, then xdmp:estimate is way off.. My search results are fine though.. All the indexes seems fine ? why is that the case* ? hence I reverted to the fn:count for the total search results.

This might not be anything to do with this question, but for completeness, I am adding this.. I created a custom constraint, which basically takes the constraint and converts that to a path in json.. For eg: let us say user wants to search for a supplier with name "ATCC".. so instead of user typing in the whole path, I created a custom constrain, where in it will be like the json structure and my constriant converts this to the actual json path.. so in this case the search string will look like this :  `((concept:suppliers.name:(ATCC))))` and my custom constraint `concept` convert this to the following cts:query

```
<cts:json-property-scope-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:property>suppliers</cts:property>
  <cts:json-property-scope-query>
    <cts:property>name</cts:property>
    <cts:word-query>
      <cts:text xml:lang="en">ATCC</cts:text>
      <cts:option>case-insensitive</cts:option>
      <cts:option>punctuation-insensitive</cts:option>
      <cts:option>whitespace-insensitive</cts:option>
      <cts:option>wildcarded</cts:option>
    </cts:word-query>
  </cts:json-property-scope-query>
</cts:json-property-scope-query>
```

This is my JSON Document structure

```
{
    "moniker": "",
    "entityType": "",
    "entitySubType": "",
    "abbvNumber": "",
    "bioSafetyLevel": "",
    "name": "",
    "extCorpID": "",
    "extLotID": "",
    "selectAgent": "",
    "comments": "",
      "nucleotideSeq": {
        "seq": ""
      },
      "chains": [
        {

          "chainType": "",
          "name": "",
          "plasmidLotID": "",
          "stochiometry": 0,
          "aminoAcids": [
            {
              "sequence": "",
              "predictedMatureSeqs": [
                {
                  "encodedChainName": "",
                  "encodedChainType": "",
                  "sequence": "",
                  "domains": [
                    {
                      "allotype": "",
                      "domainType": "",
                      "entrezgeneID": "",
                      "geneSymbol": "",
                      "heavyChainIsoType": "",
                      "lightChainIsoType": "",
                      "name": "",
                      "regonizedAntigenFK": "",
                      "species": "",
                      "heavyChainIsoTypeMutation": "",
                      "antigens": [
                        {

                          "antiIdiotypeType": "",
                          "antibodyAntigen": "",
                          "corporateID": "",
                          "description": "",
                          "entrezgeneID": "",
                          "geneSymbol": "",
                          "name": "",
                          "relatedProtein": "",
                          "sequence": "",
                          "species": "",
                          "type": "",
                          "externalID": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "domains": [
                {
                  "allotype": "",
                  "domainType": "",
                  "entrezgeneID": "",
                  "geneSymbol": "",
                  "heavyChainIsoType": "",
                  "lightChainIsoType": "",
                  "name": "",
                  "regonizedAntigenFK": "",
                  "species": "",
                  "heavyChainIsoTypeMutation": "",
                  "antigens": [
                    {

                      "antiIdiotypeType": "",
                      "antibodyAntigen": "",
                      "corporateID": "",
                      "description": "",
                      "entrezgeneID": "",
                      "geneSymbol": "",
                      "name": "",
                      "relatedProtein": "",
                      "sequence": "",
                      "species": "",
                      "type": "",
                      "externalID": ""
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "constructs": [
            {
              "plasmidID": "",
              "precursorAminoAcidSeq": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "supplier": {
        "name": "",
        "productID": "",
        "atccCatalogNumber": "",
        "lotID": ""
      },
      "preparation": {
        "type": "",
        "lotIDs": [
          ""
        ],
        "amminoAcidDerivatization": "",
        "chemicalConjugations": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "dar": ""
          }
        ],
        "peptidateTreatment": "",
        "proteinTreatment": "",
        "purification": "",
        "expressionSystem": "",
        "empty": false
      }
    },
    "project": {

      "name": "",
      "status": ""
    },
    "registrar": {
      "username": "",
      "email": "",
      "name": "",
      "upi": "",
      "admin": false,
      "curator": false,
      "approvedUser": false
    },
    "scientist": {
      "username": "",
      "email": "",
      "name": "",
      "upi": "",
      "admin": false,
      "curator": false,
      "approvedUser": false
    },
    "notebook": {

      "elnPage": "",
      "upi": "",
      "location": "",
      "subpage": ""
    },
    "growthFS": {

      "mediumUsed": "",
      "otherComponents": "",
      "percentCO2": 0,
      "percentHumudity": 0,
      "percentSerum": 0,
      "selectionMarker": "",
      "spinnerPlateSpeed": 0,
      "temp": 0,
      "drugResistance": "",
      "growthConditions": "",
      "passageNumber": ""
    },
    "origin": {

      "dateOfTransfection": "",
      "hcAntibodyIsotype": "",
      "lcAntibodyIsotype": "",
      "parentCellLineLotID": "",
      "parentChildRel": "",
      "parentTissueSpecies": "",
      "strain": "",
      "tissueSource": "",
      "celllineMemID": "",
      "dateFrozen": "",
      "strFingerprint": "",
      "plasmidLotIDs": [
        ""
      ]
    },
    "miscellaneous": {

      "expHostType": "",
      "selEukaryote": "",
      "selProkaryote": "",
      "buffer": "",
      "enotoxinLevel": "",
      "enotoxinUnit": "",
      "enotoxinMethod": "",
      "concentrationLevel": "",
      "concentrationUnit": "",
      "concentrationMethod": "",
      "mixture": "",
      "proteinMw": 0
    },
    "nucleotideSeq": {
      "seq": ""
    },
    "preparation": {

      "type": "",
      "lotIDs": [
        ""
      ],
      "amminoAcidDerivatization": "",
      "chemicalConjugations": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "dar": ""
        }
      ],
      "peptidateTreatment": "",
      "proteinTreatment": "",
      "purification": "",
      "expressionSystem": "",
      "empty": false
    },
    "adc": {

      "dars": [
        {
          "value": 0,
          "method": "",
          "precision": "",
          "empty": false
        }
      ],
      "aggregations": [
        {
          "percentAggMethod": "",
          "percentAggValue": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    "createdBy": "",
    "createdDate": "",
    "modifiedBy": "",
    "modifiedDate": "",
    "alternateName": "",
    "chains": [
      {

        "chainType": "",
        "name": "",
        "plasmidLotID": "",
        "stochiometry": 0,
        "aminoAcids": [
          {
            "sequence": "",
            "predictedMatureSeqs": [
              {

                "avgMolWt": 0,
                "encodedChainName": "",
                "encodedChainType": "",
                "length": 0,
                "sequence": "",
                "domains": [
                  {

                    "allotype": "",
                    "domainType": "",
                    "domainEnd": 0,
                    "entrezgeneID": "",
                    "geneSymbol": "",
                    "heavyChainIsoType": "",
                    "lightChainIsoType": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "regonizedAntigenFK": "",
                    "species": "",
                    "domainStart": 0,
                    "heavyChainIsoTypeMutation": "",
                    "antigens": [
                      {

                        "antiIdiotypeType": "",
                        "antibodyAntigen": "",
                        "corporateID": "",
                        "description": "",
                        "entrezgeneID": "",
                        "geneSymbol": "",
                        "name": "",
                        "relatedProtein": "",
                        "sequence": "",
                        "species": "",
                        "type": "",
                        "externalID": ""
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "domains": [
              {

                "allotype": "",
                "domainType": "",
                "domainEnd": 0,
                "entrezgeneID": "",
                "geneSymbol": "",
                "heavyChainIsoType": "",
                "lightChainIsoType": "",
                "name": "",
                "regonizedAntigenFK": "",
                "species": "",
                "domainStart": 0,
                "heavyChainIsoTypeMutation": "",
                "antigens": [
                  {

                    "antiIdiotypeType": "",
                    "antibodyAntigen": "",
                    "corporateID": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "entrezgeneID": "",
                    "geneSymbol": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "relatedProtein": "",
                    "sequence": "",
                    "species": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "externalID": ""
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "constructs": [
          {
            "plasmidID": "",
            "precursorAminoAcidSeq": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "orfs": [
      {

        "orfEnd": 0,
        "intronsPresent": "",
        "orfStart": 0,
        "promoters": [
          ""
        ],
        "aminoAcids": [
          {
            "sequence": "",
            "predictedMatureSeqs": [
              {
                "encodedChainName": "",
                "encodedChainType": "",
                "length": 0,
                "sequence": "",
                "domains": [
                  {

                    "allotype": "",
                    "domainType": "",
                    "domainEnd": 0,
                    "entrezgeneID": "",
                    "geneSymbol": "",
                    "heavyChainIsoType": "",
                    "lightChainIsoType": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "regonizedAntigenFK": "",
                    "species": "",
                    "domainStart": 0,
                    "heavyChainIsoTypeMutation": "",
                    "antigens": [
                      {

                        "antiIdiotypeType": "",
                        "antibodyAntigen": "",
                        "corporateID": "",
                        "description": "",
                        "entrezgeneID": "",
                        "geneSymbol": "",
                        "name": "",
                        "relatedProtein": "",
                        "sequence": "",
                        "species": "",
                        "type": "",
                        "externalID": ""
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "domains": [
              {
                "allotype": "",
                "domainType": "",
                "domainEnd": 0,
                "entrezgeneID": "",
                "geneSymbol": "",
                "heavyChainIsoType": "",
                "lightChainIsoType": "",
                "name": "",
                "regonizedAntigenFK": "",
                "species": "",
                "domainStart": 0,
                "heavyChainIsoTypeMutation": "",
                "antigens": [
                  {

                    "antiIdiotypeType": "",
                    "antibodyAntigen": "",
                    "corporateID": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "entrezgeneID": "",
                    "geneSymbol": "",
                    "name": "",
                    "relatedProtein": "",
                    "sequence": "",
                    "species": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "externalID": ""
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "ncSeq": {

          "seq": ""
        },
        "label": "",
        "note": ""
      }
    ],
    "antigens": [
      {

        "antiIdiotypeType": "",
        "antibodyAntigen": "",
        "corporateID": "",
        "description": "",
        "entrezgeneID": "",
        "geneSymbol": "",
        "name": "",
        "relatedProtein": "",
        "sequence": "",
        "species": "",
        "type": "",
        "externalID": ""
      }
    ],
    "immunogens": [
      {

        "type": "",
        "name": "",
        "entrezgeneID": "",
        "geneSymbol": "",
        "corporateID": "",
        "species": "",
        "lotID": "",
        "sequence": ""
      }
    ],
    "suppliers": [
      {

        "name": "",
        "productID": "",
        "atccCatalogNumber": "",
        "lotID": ""
      }
    ],
    "domains": [
      {

        "allotype": "",
        "domainType": "",
        "domainEnd": 0,
        "entrezgeneID": "",
        "geneSymbol": "",
        "heavyChainIsoType": "",
        "lightChainIsoType": "",
        "name": "",
        "regonizedAntigenFK": "",
        "species": "",
        "domainStart": 0,
        "heavyChainIsoTypeMutation": "",
        "antigens": [
          {

            "antiIdiotypeType": "",
            "antibodyAntigen": "",
            "corporateID": "",
            "description": "",
            "entrezgeneID": "",
            "geneSymbol": "",
            "name": "",
            "relatedProtein": "",
            "sequence": "",
            "species": "",
            "type": "",
            "externalID": ""
          }
        ]
      }
 }
```

Comment: You will likely need to refactor your documents so they are one-to-one with your search query and expression. However, without example XML and queries, it's not really possible to make a recommendation.

Comment: I update my question with more details about how I my documents are structured and how I am doing my search

Answer (score 1):

Sam Mefford provided the better answer in his comment- "Also keep in mind filtered vs unfiltered search. If you get your queries and all the indexes right so you can run unfiltered searches your queries will run faster and I believe your search:estimate and search:search total will be accurate."

fn:count() is never optimal. Only use it for counting small sequences, document sets, result sets, etc. Filtered search is also significantly slower than unfiltered search. If you tune your indexing, you can get unfiltered search that comes back with accurate counts from search:estimate, xdmp:estimate, and search:search pagination.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about fragments and the fact that the number you see is based on estimates from fragments. If you don't see what you expect, then there are a few options (change docs, fragment roots/parents, filtered searches etc).. But,  as `wst` mentions - give an example and then people will be able to give you more direct guidance..

Comment: I update my question with more details about how I my documents are structured and how I am doing my search

Answer (score 0):

I took a performance hit, but was able to solve using `fn:count`

I was using `search:search` with custom constraints, so in my case all I had to do was the following

```
fn:count(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:query(search:parse($q, $options))))
```

Comment: custom constraints are not the cause of the difference between the estimate and and fn:count.. Plus, the solution you propose does not scale well.

Comment: Also keep in mind filtered vs unfiltered search.  If you get your queries and all the indexes right so you can run unfiltered searches your queries will run faster and I believe your search:estimate and search:search total will be accurate.

Comment: [Using fn:count vs. xdmp:estimate](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/count_estimate) -- essential reading for anyone considering this approach.

Comment: I update my question with more details about how I my documents are structured and how I am doing my search

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any [fragmentation strategy](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fragments) defined, [xdmp:estimate](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:estimate) should give the correct result. It would be much faster than [fn:count](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:count).
You can rewrite the code like -

> xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:query(search:parse($q, $options))))